# What type of rotational invariance information can I get from interest points (coordinates) of corners from an image?

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, machine-learning, data-analysis, matrix-norms

Assume that you are using the FAST algoritm for corner/feature detection. You pick an image and run the FAST algorithm.

[image]

**Question:**

All these green dots are actully coordinates in x and y direction. What type of *rotational invariance* information can I get from only knowing the coordinates that are created by the geometical shapes inside the image?

For example: If we measure the angles between every point, the angles are going to be the same, no matter how we rotates the image.

**NOTE**

This is a feature detection algorithm, sometimes one or more coordinates can flicker e.g some green dots disapear and appears few milliseconds after.